# Python str.format - Get (only) the sign of a number?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Using Python's [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, is there a format string which will extract only the sign of a numeric argument?

More specifically, I need to be able to print the sign and the rest of the numeric argument separately in order to insert a character between them. This may be a space (e.g. turning `a -4` into `a - 4`) or a custom base prefix, (e.g. `$` for hexadecimal: `-$02`).

Comment: `"-$".join("a -4".split("-"))` ? or `"a -4".replace("-","-$")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no special format string. You have to write it yourself:

```
"{0}${1:02d}".format('+-'[s<0], abs(s))
```

Comment: you are cheating, and you know it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is purely for reference, digging deep into the format function you can do it just with formatting:

```
def myformat(n, base):
    fill = {'d': ' ', 'x': '$'}
    return "{:{f}=+{d}{b}}".format(n, b=base, f=fill[base], d=len(format(n, "+"+base))+1)

>>> print(myformat(100, 'd'))
+ 100
>>> print(myformat(100, 'x'))
+$64
>>> print(myformat(-100, 'x')
-$64
```

The explanation:

```
n = number
f = fill character
= = pad after sign
+ = show sign
d = number of digits to pad to (number of digits of n with sign + 1 for pad char)
b = integer base
```